# How to notify a handler at the end of execution?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a Rackspace instance that I use for testing. I am using a seperate user for running Ansible, and due to my SSH configuration update tasks, if I notify the "restart ssh" task when needed, later tasks are failed due to a SSH connection error.

Is there a way to schedule a handler to be executed when the playbook execution is completed?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say given the little information of your setup, but there is a `post_task` feature that might do what you want.  I couldn't find a terribly in depth description of its functionality, but you can find it mentioned in the [Ansible Playbook documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html.).